# Integral of volume of a solid of revolution

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification, solid-of-revolution

[image: img]

Hello! I was practicing for my upcoming math test, but I wasn't sure about this problem. I think I did it right, but I just wanted to check to be safe. I got answer choice B. Would anyone know if that is correct? Thank you!

Comment: Why not translate everything 4 units down? This problem is equivalent to revolving the region between $y=x^2-8$ and $y=-x^2$ about the x-axis. I think your answer is clear now

Comment: Oh, thank you! I didn't even think of it that way. It's a relief to know I'm doing it right. Thank you :)

Comment: You can eliminate the first choice because the limits of integration are wrong for the given axis of revolution.  For integration along the $ \ x-$ direction, $ \ x^2 - 4 \ $ is the parabola farther from the axis:  the third choice ignores the "hole" in the "disk" produced by $ \ 4 - x^2 \ \ , $ and the fourth choice uses the wrong parabola, $ \ 4 - x^2 \ , $ as the "edge" of the disk.